# How do I create an emptry LineString in GeoDjango

Tags: django, geodjango, geos

I am having a problem with the latest version of the `GeoDjango` extensions in Django version 4.2.6 when I create an empty `LineString`. The same code is behaving differently than it did in version 4.0.10. The default seems to have switched to creating a Geos object with 3-dimensions rather than the previous 2-dimensions.

The following code returns a different WKT object depending on the version of Django I am using.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import LineString
ls = LineString()
ls.wkt
```

This is returning a 3-dimensional object "LINESTRING Z EMPTY". Running exactly the same code on Django 4.0.10 creates a 2-dimension object "LINESTRING EMPTY".

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong? I am also running a slightly newer version of geos-3.12.0 versus 3.11.2 but I cannot see anything is both sets of release notes that describe this change in behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be due to a change in the way [geos](https://libgeos.org/) handles empty LineString objects. This has now been corrected in a patch to the master branch.
See https://github.com/libgeos/geos/issues/993 for the details of the issue and the patch that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

In GeoDjango,starting from version 3.1, 3D geometries are supported by default.
If you want to create a 2D LineString explicitly, you can use the dim parameter when creating the LineString object. Set dim=2 to create a 2D LineString.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import LineString
ls = LineString(dim=2)
print(ls.wkt)
```

Comment: That's a good theory but unfortunately even with the "dim=2" argument I still get a 3-dimensional empty LineString. If I run the above I get "LINESTRING Z EMPTY".